# How to group an array of Image Urls together in Firebase Realtime Database? (Swift)

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func postFinalButton(_ sender: Any) {
        while index < ImagesOnClick.count {
            ProgressHUD.show()
            ProgressHUD.animationType = .circleRotateChase
            ProgressHUD.colorAnimation = #colorLiteral(red: 0.337254902, green: 0.6156862745, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)
            ProgressHUD.colorHUD = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        guard let imageSelected = ImagesOnClick[index] else {
            print("Image is nil")
            return
        }
        index += 1
        guard let imageData = imageSelected.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else {
            print("This is nil")
            return
        }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://loginpage-227bd.appspot.com")
        let storageRefPosts = storageRef.child("posts").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        storageRefPosts.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: {
            (storageMetaData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                
                print("error")
                return
            }
            print("blala")
            storageRefPosts.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let metaImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                    print(metaImageUrl)
                    self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: metaImageUrl)
                    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToHome", sender: self)
                }
            })
        })
        }
    }
    func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postsRefrence = ref.child("posts")
        let newPostId = postsRefrence.childByAutoId().key
        let newPostsRefrence = postsRefrence.child(newPostId!)
        newPostsRefrence.setValue(["photoUrl": photoUrl], withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            ProgressHUD.showSucceed()
        })
    }
```

My model then looks like this:

[image]

If you look at the database you will see 4 different images each one in a separate Id. The problem is I uploaded these images all at the same time. I am trying to create an app where you can post images and then view them. However if I upload multiple images together they get stored as completely separate images. What I want is if the user uploads an array of images they get stored together so I can retrieve them as one post. My question is how would I do that?

**Edit**

I have changed my code to:

```
@IBAction func postFinalButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postsReference = ref.child("posts")
        let newImagesRef = postsReference.childByAutoId()
        while index < ImagesOnClick.count {
            ProgressHUD.show()
            ProgressHUD.animationType = .circleRotateChase
            ProgressHUD.colorAnimation = #colorLiteral(red: 0.337254902, green: 0.6156862745, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)
            ProgressHUD.colorHUD = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        guard let imageSelected = ImagesOnClick[index] else {
            print("Image is nil")
            return
        }
        index += 1
        guard let imageData = imageSelected.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else {
            print("This is nil")
            return
        }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://loginpage-227bd.appspot.com")
        let storageRefPosts = storageRef.child("posts").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        storageRefPosts.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: {
            (storageMetaData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                
                print("error")
                return
            }
            print("blala")
            storageRefPosts.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let metaImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                    print(metaImageUrl)
                    self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: metaImageUrl, ref: postsReference, index: self.index)
                    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToHome", sender: self)
                }
            })
        })
        }
    }
    func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String, ref: DatabaseReference, index: Int) {
        let name = "photoUrl"+String(index)
        ref.setValue([name: photoUrl], withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            ProgressHUD.showSucceed()
        })
    }
```

But now when I press the post button only the last selected image url is saved, and instead of each post being stored under a new id they are stored under the posts child. Here is an image of what it looks like:

[image: Database Image]

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `childByAutoId()` it generates a new unique location in the database. Since you now call `childByAutoId()` for every image, each image gets stored under its own auto ID.

The trick is to only call `childByAutoId()` once for all images. But that means you'll need to use another unique property name for each image, as they can't all be called `photoUrl` (keys have to be unique in their parent node).

One way to do this is:

1. Call `childByAutoId()` once in the `postFinalButton` method, and pass the resulting key into `sendDataToDatabase`.
2. Use the index of each file as part of its filename, by also passing that value into `sendDataToDatabase`.

Something like this in `postFinalButton`:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
let postsReference = ref.child("posts")
let newImagesRef = postsRefrence.childByAutoId()

...

storageRefPosts.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: {
    (storageMetaData, error) in
    if error != nil {            
        print("error")
        return
    }
    storageRefPosts.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
        if let metaImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
            self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: metaImageUrl, newImagesRef, index)
        }
    })
})
```

And then:

```
func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String, ref: DatabaseReference, index: int) {
    let name = "photoUrl"+String(index)
    ref.setValue([name: photoUrl], withCompletionBlock: {
        (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        ProgressHUD.showSucceed()
    })
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit, by the way I just figured out why there was not a new id being generated for each post but I am still having trouble with only the final image url being shown and not all of them. For example if there is 4 images and I go to post them, I will only see photoURL4: in the database.

Comment: Ah, I was passing the wrong reference to `sendDataToDatabase`. I updated the code in my answer now, but had hoped you'd be able to figure out minor mistakes like this based on the explanation I gave around how the process works.

Comment: That was not the issue I was having, the issue is that no matter what I do only only one imageURL is saved to the childbyautoid