# How to call childByAutoId once in a loop? (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, imageurl

Since I am uploading multiple images to firebase with one click I created a loop that goes until all the images are uploaded. Once I have uploaded the images to storage I want to save the urls in realtime firebase. This is what I have:

```
@IBAction func postFinalButton(_ sender: Any) {
        ProgressHUD.show()
        ProgressHUD.animationType = .circleRotateChase
        ProgressHUD.colorAnimation = #colorLiteral(red: 0.337254902, green: 0.6156862745, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)
        ProgressHUD.colorHUD = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
        startUploading(completion: {
            print("Done!!!")
            ProgressHUD.showSucceed()
        })
    }
    func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String, ref: DatabaseReference, index: Int) {
     print("okbud")
      let name = "photoUrl"+String(index)
        ref.setValue([name: photoUrl, "caption": "buddy"], withCompletionBlock: {
        (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        ProgressHUD.showSucceed()
      })
    }
    func startUploading(completion: @escaping FileCompletionBlock) {
         if ImagesOnClick.count == 0 {
            completion()
            return;
         }

         block = completion
         uploadImage(forIndex: 0)
    }

    func uploadImage(forIndex index:Int) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postsReference = ref.child("posts")
        let newImagesRef = postsReference.childByAutoId()

         if index < ImagesOnClick.count {
              /// Perform uploading
             let data = ImagesOnClick[index]!.pngData()
             let fileName = String(format: "%@.png", String(newImagesRef.key!))

            FirFile.shared.upload(data: data!, withName: fileName, block: { (url) in
                  /// After successfully uploading call this method again by increment the **index = index + 1**
                  print(url ?? "Couldn't not upload. You can either check the error or just skip this.")
                  self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: url!, ref: newImagesRef, index: index)
                  self.uploadImage(forIndex: index + 1)
               })
            return;
          }

          if block != nil {
             block!()
          }
    }
    
class FirFile: NSObject {

    /// Singleton instance
    static let shared: FirFile = FirFile()

    /// Path
    let kFirFileStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://loginpage-227bd.appspot.com")

    /// Current uploading task
    var currentUploadTask: StorageUploadTask?

    func upload(data: Data,
                withName fileName: String,
                block: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) {

        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        let fileRef = kFirFileStorageRef.child(fileName)

        /// Start uploading
        upload(data: data, withName: fileName, atPath: fileRef) { (url) in
            block(url)
        }
    }
    func upload(data: Data,
                withName fileName: String,
                atPath path:StorageReference,
                block: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) {

        // Upload the file to the path
        self.currentUploadTask = path.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
             guard let metadata = metaData else {
                  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                  block(nil)
                  return
             }
             // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
             // let size = metadata.size
             // You can also access to download URL after upload.
             path.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                  guard let downloadURL = url else {
                     // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                     block(nil)
                     return
                  }
                 block(downloadURL.absoluteString)
             }
        }
    }

    func cancel() {
        self.currentUploadTask?.cancel()
    }
}
}
```

However the images get stored like this:
[image]
When I want them to be stored like this:
[image]

How would I do this?

Comment: Please don't repost the same problem multiple times. If you have more information to add, click the `edit` link under your previous question to make those changes.

Comment: This is a completely different question, my first one was asking how to upload multiple images to storage while this is asking how to save image urls to Firebase under one childbyautoid

Comment: A couple of things. You are probably not going to want to use either structure presented in the question. Secondly the code in the question isn't very helpful to us as  it doesn't directly have anything to do with writing data to Firebase e.g. we dont know what these functions do`self.sendDataToDatabase`, `self.uploadImage` or `FirFile.shared.upload`. More importantly or maybe MOST importantly, you need to get the download url (where the image is stored) from the *firebase* function that actually stores the image in Firebase Storage. That seems to be omitted.

Comment: The code in the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Upload Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) is applicable to what you're attempting to do so please review it, update the question with more details and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay I have just edited my question to all of my code, right now when I press the post button all the images get stored to firebase storage with a childbyautoid as there name

Comment: Why aren't you following the firebase guide? It's a matter of loading each image, passing it to a function similar to the one in the guide and then storing it. Do that for each image you want to store.

Answer (score -1):

I declared a varaible:

```
var childByAutoId = String()
```

Then when the `viewDidLoad` I assigned the function `childByAutoId()` to the variable `childByAutoId`

```
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postsReference = ref.child("posts")
        let newImagesRef = postsReference.childByAutoId()
        childByAutoId = newImagesRef.key!
```

And finally:

```
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postsReference = ref.child("posts")
        let newImagesRef = postsReference.child(childByAutoId)
```

```
self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: url!, ref: newImagesRef, index: index)
```

Comment if you have any questions!

Comment: Is this an answer? If so, it's very unclear what the purpose of this code is. Can you please explain the purpose and add it to your *question* if you're adding additional details.

Comment: @Jay: see my answer here, where I pretty much proposed precisely that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165715/how-to-group-an-array-of-image-urls-together-in-firebase-realtime-database-swi

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes you did! This is clearly a duplicate question because its the same problem as in the other question. Marked it as such.